# Symfony doctrine refclass: weird

Tags: orm, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a weird behaviour with refClass relationship:

```yml
User:
 [.....]
MyFriends: {class: User, refClass: UserFriend, local: id_owner, foreign: id_friend, type: many}

UserFriend:
  columns:
    id_owner: {type: integer(8)}
    id_friend: {type: integer(8)}
  relations:
    Owner: {class: User, local: id_owner, foreign: id, type: one}
    Friend: {class: User, local: id_friend, foreign: id, type: one}
```

where `id_owner` is the "owner" of the friend relationship and `id_friend` is the friend.
However, when I try to get `$user->getMyFriends()` I get the same `$user` as result.

What is wrong in my schema?

Answer (score 0):

a friendship relationship is an [equal nest relation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/defining-models.html#equal-nest-relations). It seems you are missing the `equal: true` bit show in the example. Plus, you really don't need to define relations in the refClass.